# Nodes() function returns relationships?

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I have installed version 2.2.5 community edition to my machine. Downloaded sample data set `cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors_2.1.6`. Followed the online training, all is good, except one query confused me a little.

```
match p = shortestPath( 
    (kevin {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(keanu {name:"Keanu Reeves"}) 
) return nodes(p)
```

I was expecting that the returned values would only be the nodes. Reading the manual about nodes() it sounds like it should only return nodes. However I am getting both nodes and relationships in this case. Am I missing something here or is this a defect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeing relationships in the Neo4j browser you can turn off "Auto-Complete" - look in the bottom right for the toggle. By default relationships between nodes returned in the browser are shown in the visual, even if not returned in the query.

Example

With auto-complete:

[image]

Without auto-complete:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply ! After turning off the auto-complete I see that only nodes are displayed. However when I switch to "Rows" view instead of "Graph" view, I still see nodes and relationships listed in the results

Comment: Could you post an image of the rows view?

Comment: Apparently StackOverflow does not let me append images since I am a new users ?!? Let me see if I can append the result set to the original posting

Comment: Actually, now I see where I was confused. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I am using neo4j 3.2.0 and cannot see the AUTO-COMPLETE button in either Firefox or Chrome. Does it still exist?

Comment: @JanekBogucki auto-complete has been removed in Neo4j 3.2.

Comment: @WilliamLyon - The UI element was moved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165484/does-neo4j-browser-auto-complete-toggle-exist-in-3-2-0