# Does Neo4j browser AUTO-COMPLETE toggle exist in 3.2.0?

Tags: neo4j

According to [Nodes() function returns relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981525) there is an AUTO-COMPLETE toggle in the Neo4j browser. I am using 3.2.0 which does not have this. Is there a equivalent UI element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it moved to the bottom of the browser settings gear and is now labeled `Connect result nodes`. It defaults to checked. If you uncheck the box it appears as though it behaves like the autocomplete slider did previously.

[image]

Comment: Kind of an awkward shift I think. To my knowledge the slider won't return in the 3.2 browser, but there's opportunity for change come version 3.3 later in the year.

Comment: Thanks. My first impression is that this would be better restored to the console output because that would allow per-query settings.

Comment: agree with both - in the old location one could turn it on and off for a query that was already rendered. Now it needs to be set before the query is executed. Can still leave the left nave set there but it is not quite as convenient imo.

Comment: This checkbox does something else than described in this answer, if checked, after a cypher query result is achieved, a second query is fetched to create relationships between nodes. This is revealed by hovering your mouse over it to reveal a pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

In the neo4j browser, click on the "Browser Settings" cog icon in the bottom left.

This reveals the Browser settings tab. Look under the "User Interface" section and you'll see a check box for "Enhanced query editor". If you hover over it, a pop-up says that it enables autocomplete and syntax highlighting in the query editor.

Ensure this is checked.

Now start to type:
`MATCH ()`

On typing the first parenthesis you should see some autocomplete nodes displayed.